# Can we always find a proper step size?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In convex optimization, if we know the gradient of a function $f(x)$, then is it true that we could always find a way to determine a proper step size in the gradient descent method? When I say "proper" I mean it only need to be proper enough to make the funciton $f$ converge to the optimum.

Comment: You clearly need additional assumptions on the smoothness of $f$ (Lipschitz gradient e.g.)

Comment: Do you want the the iterates to converge to a solution or the function values to converge to the optimal objective value?

Comment: Im sorry but what is the difference?